# Google guice not working without using implemented by

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I have a interface  as

```
public interface ConfFileLoader {

    public Map<String, Object> getResultMap() throws SecurityException, IOException;
}
```

and a class that imlements it as

```
public class ConfYamlLoader implements ConfFileLoader{

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getResultMap() throws SecurityException, IOException {

    }

}
```

and has a injector class as

```
public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(ConfFileLoader.class).to(ConfYamlLoader.class);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is i have a class as

```
public class TI {


    @Inject
    private ConfFileLoader confFileLoader;


    public void test(){
        System.out.println("yeah tesrintY>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+confFileLoader);
    }

}
```

and it gives exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for com.exzeo.conf.ConfFileLoader was bound.
  while locating com.exzeo.conf.ConfFileLoader
    for field at com.exzeo.automate.HCPCI.TI.confFileLoader(TI.java:10)
  while locating com.exzeo.automate.HCPCI.TI
```

but when i do @ConfYamlLoader it works fine as

```
public class TI {


    @Inject
    private ConfYamlLoader confFileLoader;


    public void test(){
        System.out.println("yeah tesrintY>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+confFileLoader);
    }

}
```

This above class works fine

So on investigation I found when I add @implemetedby on ConfFileLoader it works fine as

```
@ImplementedBy(ConfYamlLoader.class)
public interface ConfFileLoader {

    public Map<String, Object> getResultMap() throws SecurityException, IOException;
}
```

I can't understand this behaviour that why i need to do @ImplementedBy if I  am already binding it in binding module. As I per my understanding @implementedby is equavlane to bind().

Let me know if I am missing anything and I am using guice version 3

Comment: The only reason this can happen is that you're not using your module at all. Check once more that you indeed are passing `AppInjector` instance to `Guice.createInjector()`.

Comment: Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector()); I am doing this @VladimirMatveev

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't reproduce your problem. Please see [this](https://gist.github.com/netvl/49f73211bd68f4fb30f1) gist. It contains exactly the code you have provided and a small piece of glue code in Main. It works perfectly for me, printing `guicex.ConfYamlLoader@5dbc26ee` when `test()` method is called.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Sorry I didn't mention something important. I am usin testng To run a test class and in that class I am injecting ConFileLoader. I am uisng testng as     
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(xmlSuiteBuilder.getSuites());
        tng.run();
xml suite builder give details of Test Class

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
bind(ConfFileLoader.class).to(ConfYamlLoader.class);
```

means "whenever you're going to inject a value of type `ConfFileLoader`, instead inject a value of type `ConfYamlLoader` and use that".

But you still need to bind `ConfYamlLoader` somehow so that it can be injected.

If it has an `@Inject`-annotated constructor, or a public no-args constructor (unless you've called `binder.requireAtInjectOnConstructors()` somewhere), then Guice will use that.

Otherwise, you'll need to bind a `Provider<ConfYamlLoader>` somehow, either by using a `@Provides ConfYamlLoader` method or `bind(ConfYamlLoader).toProvider(...)` or `.toInstance(...)`.